# Navigation at the top with active icons?

Tags: flutter

Firstly I used AppBar to change pages, but I noticed BottomNavBar has better properties to do that. But it would be great if someone gave me a clue to create navigation at the top of the screen.
This BottomNavBar doesn't work, gives error 'each child must be laid once':

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      //appBar: bar(context),
      body: new Container(
        key: _formKey,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: BottomNavigationBar(
                  items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("Home")),
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.work),
                        title: new Text("Self Help")),
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.face),
                        title: new Text("Profile"))
                  ],
                  selectedItemColor: colorGold,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my AppBar where I tried to change color of the active icon:

````
AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Center(
          child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <
              Widget>[
        iconButton(
            Icons.home,
            ),
        iconButton(
            Icons.work,
            ),
        iconButton(
            Icons.face,
            )),]))```
````

Comment: Are you trying to implementing top navigation tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong , you are supposing to this:

[image]

Use `PreferredSize` widget in your app bar

Full code:

```
class TabBarHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabBarHomeScreenState createState() => _TabBarHomeScreenState();
}

class _TabBarHomeScreenState extends State<TabBarHomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Top Navigation tab bar demo"),
      ),
      body: TopNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}


class TopNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TopNavigationBarState createState() => _TopNavigationBarState();
}

class _TopNavigationBarState extends State<TopNavigationBar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin  {
  int tabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold( 
      appBar:PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
            //elevation: 0.0,
            items:  <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.grey,),
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.blue,),
                title: Text('')
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.grey,),
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.blue,),
                title: Text('')
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.grey,),
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.blue,),
                title: Text('')
              )
            ],
            currentIndex: tabIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            onTap: (int index){
              setState(() {
                tabIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),

      ),
      body:  Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: tabIndex ==0 ?MyHomeScreen() 
      :tabIndex == 1? MyMailScreen(): MyProfileScreen()
    ),

    );
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:Text("My Home Screen")

      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyMailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:Text("My Mail Screen")

      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:Text("My Profile Screen")

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes, that's what I meant. I copied this code to check it out and the bar is cut from the top. It is covered by the original bar of the phone (with the time). Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: May I see your page screenshot?

Comment: So you don't want to add app bar? Then give some margin from top.

Comment: That's it, but how can I add margin for appBar only? I wrapped it in widget like this: return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            PreferredSize(..., but it gives me an error: https://imgur.com/a/4IDSzft

Comment: No no you are doing wrong, no need to wrap your body constructor widget, just wrap BottomNavigationBar with container and then give margin from top, it will give margin for appbar widgets. Or you can also give padding into PreferredSize widget with fixed value like `Size.fromHeight(80)`